# Open fancybox5 iframe automatically without click on page load

Tags: javascript, fancybox

How can I open fancybox5 without click, my basic code for click is:

```
Fancybox.bind("[data-fancybox=\'iframe3\']", {
    defaultType:"iframe",
    on: {
        "destroy": (fancybox, eventName) => {
                window.location.reload();
        },
    },
});
```

and link:

```
<a data-fancybox="iframe3" data-preload="false" href="https://google.com"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of ways to launch Fancybox on page load.

#1 Start from previously used selector

```js
Fancybox.fromSelector('[data-fancybox="iframe3"]');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jqwx9pfm/ 
https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/getting-started/#launch-by-specifying-a-selector-or-elements

#2 Start using `Fancybox.show()` API method

```js
Fancybox.show([{
  src : "https://google.com",
  type: "iframe" 
}], {
  on: {
    "destroy": (fancybox, eventName) => {
      window.location.reload();
    },
  },
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wejs9kz7/ 
https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/getting-started/#option-2-programmatic